# Getting threads to share data correctly in python

Tags: python

Created a gui with three buttons, one to execute a program, one to halt program, and one to clear the textbuffer . Also have a textview to display text from program. Here are the pertenant functions.

```
def clear_display(self, widget):
    global textbuffer
    start = textbuffer.get_start_iter()
    end = textbuffer.get_end_iter()
    textbuffer.delete(start, end)
    self.print_display("")

def start_program(self):
    global textbuffer
    global mythread 
    global run
    i = 0
    while run:
        msg = "Count = %s\n" % i
        self.print_display(msg) 
        print ( "Count = %s\n" % i)
        i += 1
    mythread._Thread__stop()

def start_run(self, widget):
    global run
    global mythread
    run = 1
    mythread = Thread(target=self.start_program, args=())
    mythread.start()

def stop_run(self, widget):
    global run  
    global textbuffer
    msg = "Halt Run\n"
    self.print_display(msg)
    run = 0

def print_display(self, msg):
    global  textbuffer
    start = textbuffer.get_start_iter()
    end = textbuffer.get_end_iter()
    text = textbuffer.get_text(start, end)
    text = text + msg
    textbuffer.set_text(text)
```

The problem I am having is getting the data to display to the textview. Initial run will produce a partial display. If I press the button clear to the display then press the start button, I will receive some data and some data from the previous display interleaved which should have been deleted. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: I need information to be displayed asynchroncing. Not in a fifo or lifo queue. A aueue would be too restrictive and display only after task is performed. The thread will contain many tasks with information to be displayed at time of each task. The main thread is to run the gui while subthread performs program tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) I'll leave your implementation to you, but the classic use is:

```
import threading, queue

q = queue.Queue()

def make_something(q, num_things_to_make):
    for _ in num_things_to_make
        new_thing = make_a_thing()
        q.put(new_thing)

def use_something(q):
    while True:
        thing_to_use = q.get()
        do_a_thing(thing_to_use)
        q.task_done()

producer = threading.Thread(target=lambda: make_something(q, 8))
producer.start()

for _ in range(num_workers):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=lambda: use_something(q))
    worker.daemon = True
    worker.start()

q.join() # block until all tasks are done
```